# Retrieve all IDs using PHP from a structured log string

Tags: php, arrays, json, loops

I need to somehow handle the following recursive log output using PHP, creating an array or encoding it in json, the ultimate goal is to retrieve the "id" value of each getusers section, i've done some tests but i can't get a good result.

This is just a portion of the log string containing all the getusers sections(there can be thousands):

```
getusers:           {
"user": {
    "id": 1569976517,
    "type": "user",
    "first_name": "Mike",
    "username": "MikesNick",
    "verified": false,
    "restricted": false,
    "status": {
        "_": "userStatusRecently"
    },
    "access_hash": -7018287513210933137,
    "bot_nochats": false
},
"date": 1613450429,
"role": "user"
}
getusers:           {
"user": {
    "id": 717418136,
    "type": "user",
    "first_name": "John",
    "last_name": "Smith",
    "username": "JhonsNick",
    "verified": false,
    "restricted": false,
    "status": {
        "_": "userStatusOffline",
        "was_online": 1613230815
    },
    "access_hash": 1814429223003924316,
    "bot_nochats": false
},
"date": 1613245788,
"role": "user"
}
```

What is the best way to manage it and recover the data I need?

Comment: Is the complete log valid JSON? This part isn't?

Comment: @0stone0 can't manage the getusers: part

Comment: @MattC that isn't what you were asked. P.S. If you've an attempt at solving this, it would make sense to show your code, then we know where you're up to and have a better idea where you're stuck

Comment: its invalid json

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a way to extract the IDs from the log using the following code

```
$exploded = explode("getusers:",$logString);

foreach($exploded as $group){
   $decoded = json_decode($group,true);
   echo $decoded["user"]["id"]."<br/>";
}
```